# Add plot to list using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

---

### Problem

I am creating a boxplot of 14 water chemistry elements. Each element has a different dataframe. I have create a for loop to loop through each data frame and plot the appropriate graph. I want to add each of the plots to a list of plots that I have created outside of the for loop.

---

### Working Code

```
# Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

# read in all files
myFiles <- list.files(pattern= ".csv")

# create a list of all 14 data frames
dataList <- list()
for (var in myFiles) {
  filepath <- file.path(paste(var))
  dataList[[var]] <- read.csv(filepath, sep=",", header=T)
}


# Plot the data as a boxplot
for (data in dataList){
  p <-
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x='Month', y=data[,5])) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_classic() +
      labs(y= colnames(data[5])) +
      scale_x_discrete
  print(p)
}
```

---

### Attempts

**Attempt 1:**

```
# Plot the data and add to list
bplot_list <- list()
for (data in dataList){
  plot_list[[data]] <-
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x='Month', y=data[,5])) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_classic() +
      labs(y= colnames(data[5])) +
      scale_x_discrete
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
# Plot the data and add to list
bplot_list <- list()
for (data in dataList){
  p <-
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x='Month', y=data[,5])) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_classic() +
      labs(y= colnames(data[5])) +
      scale_x_discrete
  bplot_list[[]] <- p
}
```

Comment: The code isn't reproducible so not completely sure what you are trying to achieve. But can't you just append the list from the for loop with the other list by using `append(list1, list2)` or if you want to combine both lists based on the element names `Map(list1, list2)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot multiple dataframes with lapply in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060693/plot-multiple-dataframes-with-lapply-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. I created a name for the graph based off the column name and used this to add to the list.

```
# Plot the data and add to list
bplot_list <- list()
for (data in dataList){
  chemElement <- colnames(data[5])
  p <-
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x='Month', y=data[,5])) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_classic() +
      labs(y= chemElement) +
      scale_x_discrete()
  bplot_list[[chemElement]] <- p
```

}

Comment: Very good suggestion, who helped me a lot. However, but please note, in my case it's works when I put `chemElement <-paste("colnames", x)` with  and not when I do `chemElement <-colnames(paste("colnames", x))`. I don't know if this is an error in your code or if `colname` works in your situation.